# Program Icon Is Noisy

Tags: c#, icons, executable

I have compiled my program with **256x256** resolution ICON but my program icon is very noisy , you can see in this image :

[image: PROGRAM ICON]

How to fix this ?

Comment: You need to include various icon sizes as when it scales them it is less good than you specifically designing it so.

Comment: Use proper .ico file which contains different resolution images (16x16, 32x32, 96x96 etc up to 256x256).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue using [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/).
I recommended it, It's a great application